# Doctrine not returning (non-autoincrement) id field for entity when fetching by other column

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that has `id` column as its primary key. The column, however, is not an auto_increment field.

When I get entities from the repository with `$entity = $repository->find($id)` an entity with the correct `id` property is returned. When I get the entity with `$entity = $repository->findOneByName($name)` the entity ends up having zero as the `id` property's value, which is incorrect.

How can I get the correct id column value?

**EDIT:** Solved. See my comment...

Comment: Do you have a custom **findOneByName** method on your repository class ? Could you show us what it looks like ?

Comment: @ThomasPiard nope, I don't have a custom repository class. I also get int(0) as the value for the id property when I try `$entity = $repository->findOneBy(array('name'=>$name))`

Comment: THIS IS EMBARRASSING. It turns out I had mistakenly inserted another row with the same name which had a key of, you guessed it, zero...